# How to set different access levels for dashboard data in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

Lets assume I am creating a google DataStudio dashboard for a sales data which is having sales records for countries.
For each country has a country manager and they are assign to single supervisor in Head Office.

My question is:
Can we develop a Google DataStudio DashBoard which is capable to restrict data only relevant to a particular country if it is viewing by a country manager and to show whole data relevant to all countries if it is viewing by the supervisor of country managers?

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy solution to have a page-level permission, but there are three options.

1. Break up the report in to separate ones (this is the most simple solution, although it creates multiple reports)
2. Use [Viewer's credentials instead of Owners’ credential](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10403868?hl=en#credentials) (You must grand viewers access to your gbq data source, which is not ideal in most cases)
3. [Filter by email](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713766?hl=en) (This works for small number of users, but quite cumbersome for multiple users)

For the option one, you can break up one "master report" that has all pages, and creating multiple sub-reports by using URL embedding by page

Answer (score 0):

In your Data Source, create a column called "e-mail" and populate it with the e-mail address of the manager that you want to be able to see that particular line.

After you do this, use the "Filter by email" option in the Data Source:

[image: Filter by email option]

And select the field you just created:

[image: Selecting email field]

And there you are.  Your data will only be searchable by the person you selected, based on the email they are using to access the dashboard.

If you want more than one person to be able to see a particular data, you'll need to duplicate the respective lines in the Data Source.